# Collection of exercises

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if there is a collection of algebraic geometry exercises out there, solutions would be great too. More specifically pre-Schemes. I tackled most of the exercises inside Hartshrone but would like some further training.

Comment: Looks good, thank you.

Comment: There are more actually listed at MSE - have a look.